# Python, Convolve function from ndimage filters

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, filter

I have a challenge: to write `convolve` function for images 56x56 argument as array, and second arg kernel which is in my case a matrix of 1x3 or 3x1.
The point is to write `convolve(image, kernel)` using **only** `numpy`.
I have a HOG filter which is using `convolve` from `scipy` however I need that `convolve` function to work.

I have no idea how to begin, does anybody have information how it can be easily done or someone had similar thing to write before?

Comment: Have you tried [numpy.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)?

Comment: sure, that's first thing, i've done, np.convolve is only for one dim arrays and won't work with image

Answer (score 0):

If your filter is only 1D (e.g., 1x3 or 3x1) you can use 1D convolutions row-wise or column wise:

```
def my_conv(im2d, ker1d):
    out = np.zeros(im2d.shape, dtype=im2d.dtype)  # allocate output assuming mode='same' 
    if ker1d.shape[0] == 1:
        # horizontal kernel
        for row in xrange(im2d.shape[0]):
            out[row,:] = np.convolve(im2d[row,:], ker1d.flatten(), mode='same')
    elif ker1d.shape[1] == 1:
        # vertical kernel
        for col in xrange(im2d.shape[1]):
            out[:,col] = np.convolve(im2d[:,col], ker1d.flatten(), mode='same')
    else:
        raise ValueError('input kernel is not 1D')
    return out
```

Comment: i've tried that too, i dont know why, but for np.convolve doesn't accept my kernels and returns "ValueError: object too deep for desired array". Maybe  my input is wrong?? Kernels are : horizontal = np.array([[1,0,-1]])
vertical = np.array([[-1],[0],[1]]).

Comment: @Joshua it appears `ker1d` needs to be `flatten()`, please see my edit.